# Check if input to macro is a vector

Tags: julia

I would like to check if the input to a macro is an vector and raise an exception if it is not. Currently, I have come up with this. Is there an idiomatic way of doing this?

```
macro doarray(arr)
    if in(:head, fieldnames(typeof(arr))) && arr.head == :vect
        println("Do Something")
    else
        throw(ArgumentError("$(arr) should be a vector"))
    end
end
```

Comment: If you want to allow only `[A, B, C, ...]` like syntax then you have to look for `:vect` in head as you write as far as I know. However, you can construct a vector also using `vcat` like this `[1;2;3]` and this pattern will not cover this (but `vcat` also can produce something else than a vector so the case is messy here).

Comment: Also take a look at [Macrotools.jl](https://github.com/MikeInnes/MacroTools.jl). You can match against `[a__]`.